# Getting Parameters from 2 different forms on Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have a simple rails view with 2 different  leading to 2 different controller routes.

```
'login'  <form> leading to a '/login'  route.
'create' <form> leading to a '/create' route.
```

I can only seem to pass my parameters to my controller from whichever form is higher up on my DOM.

How can I get the params from the second form to pass to my controller as well?

Comment: provide your view example, to understand what you have for now